# Прием REST запросов через proxy

Tags: java, spring, rest

Разбираюсь с проектом, основной разработчик которого пропал.
В этом проекте REST запросы реализованы через proxy. Со слов разработчика, это сделано для того чтобы нельзя было напрямую получить доступ к данным.
Т.е. приходит POST запрос по адресу

```
http://1.1.1.1:8000/v1/add/data
```

в этом модуле происходит проверка авторизации пользователя отправившего запрос и если все ОК, то запрос пересылается в другой модуль, по адресу

```
http://1.1.1.1:8005/v1/data
```

И в этом модуле уже происходит обработка запроса.
Я начинающий разработчик, многого еще не знаю. Но я не понимаю в чем смысл этого.
Зачем перенаправлять этот запрос в другой модуль?

Зачем вообще нужен этот proxy?
Почему во втором модуле сразу не делать проверку авторизации и там же обрабатывать запрос?

Зачем эти сложности?

Это реально Best practices?

Разработчик пропал, поэтому у него спросить уже не могу.
Возможно я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: такое могут делать для микросервисов, если не хотят, чтобы внутренние сервисы вообще были доступны извне - тогда дают доступ клиентам только к одному сервису, который уже сам опередляет, котого и когда вызывать. Зачем это вам в вашем конкретном случае мне не ведомо.

Comment: А что дает это закрытие? Один микросервис все рано остается открытым и через него моно получить доступ ко всем остальным.

Comment: 1) нет необходимости писать аутентификацию в каждом из внутренних сервисов 2) клиентам не надо знать внутренние сервисы, для них есть единое API / вебсайт, которое обо всем позаботится 3) упадет этот публичный сервис - внутренние продолжат работу - меньше точек отказа в итоге 4) ну и всякие другие плюшки. Но это имеет смысл в микросервисах, если же у вас всего 2 сервиса и прокси один из них, то тут вопрос конечно

Comment: Как варинат - есть готоовый сервис аутентификации ("proxy"), его используют в готовом виде, а всё, что связано с бизнес - логикой - пишут в отодельном сервисе. Ну это так - вариант того, почему именно так разбито на сервисы